# Examples on converting SQL Bitwise operator to C# Bitwise operator

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

This SQL statement below, when used is returned multiple rows.

Now, how exactly can I do use bitwise calculation in C# instead of the database?  I'm working on building C# version and not have to rely on using the database too much.

How exactly does C# bitwise operator works?

```
SELECT CustomerMsg 
    CustomerMsg 
FROM BookItOut_DataReloading_DealerSalesErrorCode 
WHERE ((BitwiseErrorCode & '17314086912') = BitwiseErrorCode)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# bitwise operators work the same way they work in SQL. With LINQ you can do something like this:

```
// note that 17314086912 does not fit to int
BookItOut_DataReloading_DealerSalesErrorCode
   .Where(x => (x.BitwiseErrorCode & 17314086912) == x.BitwiseErrorCode)
   .Select(x => x.CustomerMsg);
```

From [& Operator (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c.aspx):

> Binary & operators are predefined for the integral types and bool. For integral types, & computes the logical bitwise AND of its operands. For bool operands, & computes the logical AND of its operands; that is, the result is true if and only if both its operands are true.

Example:

```
int a = 3;
int b = 6;
int c = a & b; // c will be set to 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the same operators in Integers types.

```
var mask = 2 << 3;
var value = 16;
Console.WriteLine((value & mask) == mask); //true
```

Bitwise Operators can be used with Enums type marked with [FlagsAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
[Flags]
enum MyEnum
{
    A = 1 << 0,   //1
    B = 1 << 1,   //2
    C = 1 << 2,   //4
    D = 1 << 3,   //8
    E = A | B | C //7
}
```

See the [MSDN Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17zwb64t.aspx)

Comment: note that in `Console.WriteLine(value & mask == mask)` operator `==` will precede `&`.